# Java - trying to prebind converse.js using bosh but not able to get the sid and rid...using the smack bosh

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, converse.js

I am trying to connect to the open fire using the smack bosh and trying to prebind the converse.js in the web page. My bosh code

```
BOSHConfiguration config = new BOSHConfiguration(false, "host", 7070, "/http-bind/", "<host>", "xmpp:127.0.0.1:5222");
BOSHConnection connection = new BOSHConnection(config);
try {
connection.connect();
connection.login("un", "pw");
String sss = connection.getConnectionID();
String bosh = connection.BOSH_URI;
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Can some one help me how to establish a bosh connection and get the required sid, rid and jid from the session....

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what library are you using here(means smack.versionX.jar) are you using here??

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this by adding the following functions in the Smack BOSHConnection library class:

```
public class BOSHConnection extends Connection {
    ...
    public String getSid() {
        return client.getSid();
    }

    public Long getRid() {
        return client.getRid();
    }
    ...
}
```

you then need to remember that the Rid is the last id used by the Smack library and for your pre-bind you need to increment this for next request.

Jid is already available via BOSHConnection.getUser();

I should also flag that to get converse pre-bind working with Smack I also had to change the BOSHConnection.login functon.

```
// Changed: preserve current api - call new pre-bind aware function
public void login(String username, String password, String resource)
        throws XMPPException {
    login(username, password, resource, false);         

}

// Added: Using original login function with prebind awareness
public void login(String username, String password, String resource, boolean preBind)         
        throws XMPPException {
    if (!isConnected()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not connected to server.");
    }

    ... unchanged

    // Indicate that we're now authenticated.
    authenticated = true;
    anonymous = false;

    // Added: Prebind only requires connect and authenticate
    if (preBind) {
        return;
    }
```

then in Web app

```
// login with pre-bind only
connection.login(userName, password, "", true);
```

This is required as the first thing converse does is perform all the roster and presence stuff that the later half of the login function does.  My reasoning here is that the XMPP server will actually see two connections (one from SMACK and one from converse) and it's the one that sends the presence which will end up being target for XMPP messages - and we want that to be converse.

Edit: Longer code sample for this is [in this other StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25465305/1265200)

Comment: Can you also show how your client.getSid() and client.getRid() are look like.

Comment: @Ulik the "client" variable is not my addition, this is an existing private variable (BOSHClient) in the Smack BOSHConnection class.  These functions are just allowing access to the internal ids.

Comment: what version of smack are you using here ,smack-core-4.0.3.jar and smack-bosh-4.0.3.jar,but unable to even log in to server,can you please tell me what library(.jar files ) are you using for above code to be able to run!!!!

Comment: Hi, I'm using 3.2.2 which is same as in linke in @Deuteu's answer - and it looks like from that that you now have things compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I allready give this tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384939/how-to-connect-xmpp-bosh-server-using-java-smack-library/) and apparently it worked for him to so here it is :

I neither did have access to client.getRid/Sid. I check in jbosh sources and discover these methods didn't exist so I had to add them.

I used jbosh sources (uncompiled then recompiled after changes) and add following lines :

```
In com.kenai.jbosh.BOSHClient class
//I introduced a new property
private Long rid;

//commented the following code
//long rid = requestIDSeq.getNextRID();
//and at that place added
this.rid = requestIDSeq.getNextRID();

//and finally added a new getter for rid
public Long getRid() {
    return rid;}
```

Then in smack-bosh :

```
In BOSHConnection.java
public Long getRid() {
    return client.getRid();}
public String getSid() {
    return sessionID;}
```