# Smack bosh - IllegalStateException while connecting

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am using Smack 4.1.8 with all the related dependencies jars.
Below is my code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    SmackConfiguration.DEBUG = true;        
    BOSHConfiguration conf = BOSHConfiguration.builder()
                            .setUsernameAndPassword("USER", "PASS")
                            .setFile("/http-bind/")
                            .setHost("BOSH_SERV")
                            .setPort(7070).setServiceName("TESTSERV")
                            .build();

    XMPPBOSHConnection connection = new XMPPBOSHConnection(conf);        
    connection.connect();
    connection.login();
    connection.disconnect();
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Exception:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load org.igniterealtime.jbosh.HTTPSender implementation
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.bosh.XMPPBOSHConnection.connectInternal(XMPPBOSHConnection.java:175)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:364)
    at converse.chat.SmackTest.main(SmackTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load org.igniterealtime.jbosh.HTTPSender implementation
    at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.ServiceLib.loadService(ServiceLib.java:83)
    at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.<init>(BOSHClient.java:235)
    at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.create(BOSHClient.java:368)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.bosh.XMPPBOSHConnection.connectInternal(XMPPBOSHConnection.java:151)
```

Thanks!

Comment: May be you are missing some dependencies.

Comment: None that I know of. Can you highlight?

Comment: Saw this thread about Smack - check if the accepted answer helps you. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384939/how-to-connect-xmpp-bosh-server-using-java-smack-library

Comment: Yep. I already saw that. In fact checked all related post in SO. Didn't work out for me.